# python error unboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script as I'm created the variable to count the value.

When I try this:

```
if action == ACTION_MOVE_DOWN:
    if allchannels_enabled:
        print "press down"
        count = 0
        print count += 1
```

I will get an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

The error are jumping on this line:

```
print count += 1
```

I want to count the value to add up in each time when I press on the down arrow button of the keyboard to get the result like this.

Results:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
...etc
```

Comment: Thank you Tony, do you know what is the proper way that I should use to allow me to count the value in each time?

Comment: I have made my comment and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your real code, as it should generate a syntax error first L

- you can't use `count +=1` as an argument to print - that is a syntax error.
- if you do `count = 0` every time, then it will never count correctly. You should only set count = 0 once before your first if

so your code would be something like :

```
count = 0 
....

if action == ACTION_MOVE_DOWN:

    if allchannels_enabled:
        print "press down"
        count += 1
        print count
```

Comment: Thank you very much but there is a problem, when I press on the down arrow button of the keyboard in each time, it is still show `1` as the output. Any idea?

Comment: @Rob This is not a helpdesk site. Please focus on a particular problem that you cannot solve with information from any basic Python tutorial. In case you have trouble with understanding a tutorial you are also free to ask a question - as long as its focused properly. Please refer to the [help].

Comment: @BartoszKP it wont get me anywhere if i look for help center, this is why i'm here. PLEASE READ MY POST ON ABOVE before you comment it.

Comment: @Rob if your counter is not incrementing correctly make sure you are only setting it to 0 once in your code. It could be that you are setting it to 0 in a loop, in which case it will reset to 0 every time you go round the loop.

Comment: @Rob This site is not about *you*. If you want to participate - please follow the rules.